# PostgreSQL - Smallint overflowing when creating index on multiple columns. Is this a bug?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.0

I was having an issue inserting the value 32767 into a `smallint` column in Postgres, which would yield the error *smallint out of range*.  This was odd because I could do:

```
SELECT 32767::int2;
```

Which would work just fine.  After a little hair pulling, I finally tracked this down to an index on the column in question.  First, here's the schema (Well, not really but I've simplified this down to a repro case):

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  cooktime smallint,
  preptime smallint,
  CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

I now create the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test_totaltime
  ON Test
  USING btree
  ((cooktime + preptime) );
```

Next, I try to create the following row:

```
INSERT INTO Test (CookTime, PrepTime, Id)
VALUES (
  (32767)::int2,
  (10)::int2,
  (E'fd47dc1e-c3c6-42c1-b058-689e926a72a4')::uuid
);
```

I get the error:

> ERROR: smallint out of range SQL state: 22003

It seems that `idx_test_totaltime` is expecting a maximum value of `int2`, even though the index is applied on the sum of two smallints.

Is this a Postgres bug, or am I missing something simple?  Is there a way to work around this *limitation*, or would I need to make these columns `int4` and use a CHECK constraint to limit each value to 32767?  I'm using Postgres 9.0.0 (Yes, I need to upgrade!) but I've created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/734d7/1) which demonstrates this error on 9.1.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `int2 + int2` is another `int2` so the expression in your index, `(cooktime + preptime)`, overflows for `(32767, 10)`. You can get around this problem with a bit of casting in the index expression:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test_totaltime
  ON Test
  USING btree
  ((cooktime::int4 + preptime::int4));
```

You only need one of the casts but using both doesn't hurt.

Comment: That works.  However, I've noticed if you do `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE CookTime + PrepTime > 100` then it will not use the index.  You have to specify `WHERE CookTime::Int4 + PrepTime::Int4 > 100` instead.  Now I have to update my search code :)

Comment: @MikeChristensen: That's a good spot on the index not getting used. I'd recommend just forget about all the `int2` business and use `int` for the column with appropriate CHECK constraints.

Comment: Cast the result of the calculation to an INT2, not the columns in the index.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: You can't cast the result in the index, the overflow will happen before the `(cooktime + preptime)::int4` cast. Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to say?

Comment: Ok, if the overflow happens before, it doesn't work. But the real problem is the usage of the wrong data type, an INT2 had nothing to do with time. What does 100 mean? 100 seconds? 100 minutes? 100 hours? Nobody knows, a recipe for bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use an [INTERVAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) for a time interval? It's a perfect solution for your problem.

Comment: That's probably a great solution as well.  Making this change now might be somewhat messy though, but I might do some experimenting to see what would be involved.  However, Mu's solution works perfectly fine as well and required me to update minimal code.